# Can't find the shutdown temperature thresholds in my UEFI BIOS

Tags: motherboard, bios, shutdown, temperature

For many years already, BIOS'es have had the feature of forcing a system shutdown if the temperature of certain components goes over some threshold.

Well, I'm looking for this feature on my Asus Z170 Pro Gaming UEFI BIOS screens, and - I can't find it. Am I missing some obscure menu somewhere or is it really missing?

My BIOS version: 3016.

Comment: I, for one, have never seen such a thing in any (ASUS) mainboard. What does the manual say on this matter?

Comment: Its been some years since I've had a board with that particular feature. I believe that its because the chip manufacturers are more consistent about implementing their own thermal shutdown safeguards, and throttling to reduce heat generation.